# Is it possible to configure CKEditor5 RemoveFormat plugin to remove lists?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using custom build of CKEditor5.

By default RemoveFormat plugin only removes styles (bold, italics, underline, alignment etc.).

Is it possible to configure it so that it removes lists (numbered and bulleted) as well?

I added the following code so that remove format button becomes enabled inside lists:

```
editor.model.schema.setAttributeProperties( 'listItem', {
    isFormatting: true
} );
editor.model.schema.setAttributeProperties( 'listStyle', {
    isFormatting: true
} );
editor.model.schema.setAttributeProperties( 'listType', {
    isFormatting: true
} );
```

I also removed `!schema.isBlock(item)` condition inside source code

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/73fcad5fb57be47becdcf6599b5ea7f3a12284ec/packages/ckeditor5-remove-format/src/removeformatcommand.ts#L76

But then I get runntime error when clicking remove format button:

```
instrument.js:108 CKEditorError: mapping-model-position-view-parent-not-found
{"modelPosition":{"root":"main","path":[0,0],"stickiness":"toNext"}}

Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-mapping-model-position-view-parent-not-found
    at on.priority (mapper.js:89:23)
    at wc.fire (emittermixin.js:146:47)
```

Any help would be appreciated